# Why does my untar not contain the last bytes

Tags: java, zip, gzip, tar

I've written a rest resource that serves a `.tar.gz` file. It's working OK. I've tried requesting it, saving the data, unpacking it (with `tar xzvf [filename]`) and I get the correct data.

However, I'm trying to use `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` and `org.apache.tools.tar.TarInputStream` to unzip and untar a `.tar.gz` that I'm serving in a JUnit test, to verify that it's working automatically. This is the code in my unit test with some details removed:

```
    HttpResponse response = <make request code here>
    byte[] receivedBytes = FileHelper.copyInputStreamToByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent(), true);

    GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedBytes));
    TarInputStream tarInputStream = new TarInputStream(gzipInputStream);
    TarEntry tarEntry = tarInputStream.getNextEntry();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
    System.out.println("Record size: " + tarInputStream.getRecordSize());
    while (tarEntry != null) // It only goes in here once
    {
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tarInputStream.copyEntryContents(byteArrayOutputStream);
        tarEntry = tarInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
    byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    byte[] archivedBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    byte[] actualBytes = <get actual bytes>
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(actualBytes, archivedBytes);
```

The final assert fails with a difference at byte `X = (n * 512) + 1`, where `n` is the greatest natural number such that `n * 512 <= l` and `l` is the length of the data. That is, I get the the biggest possible multiple of 512 bytes of data correctly, but debugging the test I can see that all the remaining bytes are zero. So, if the total amount of data is 1000 bytes, the first 512 bytes in `archivedBytes` are correct, but the last 488 are all zero / unset, and if the total data is 262272 bytes I get the first 262144 (512*512) bytes correctly, but the remaining bytes are all zero again.

Also, the `tarInputStream.getRecordSize()` System out above prints `Record size: 512`, so I presume that this is somehow related. However, since the archive works if I download it, I guess the data *must* be there, and there's just something I'm missing.

Stepping into the `tarInputStream.copyEntryContents(byteArrayOutputStream)` with the 1000 byte data, in

```
int numRead = read(buf, 0, buf.length);
```

the `numRead` is 100, but looking at the buffer, only the first 512 bytes are non-zero. Maybe I shouldn't be using that method to get the data out of the `TarInputStream`?

If anyone knows how it's supposed to work, I'd be very grateful for any advice or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was wrong in my original question, and the error *was* in the resource code. I wasn't closing the entry on the TarOutputStream when writing to it. I guess this was not causing any problems when requesting it manually from the server, maybe because the entry was closed with the connection or something, but working differently when being requested from a Unit test... though I must admit that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to be :P

Looking at the fragment of my writing code below, I was missing line 3.

```
1: tarOutputStream.putNextEntry(tarEntry);
2: tarOutputStream.write(fileRawBytes);
3: tarOutputStream.closeEntry();
4: tarOutputStream.close();
```

I didn't even know there was such a thing as a "closeEntry" on the TarOutputStream... I do now! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the output block size to be used when you create a tar archive. Thus the size of the archive will be a multiple of the block size. As the archive size doesn't normally fit in a whole number of blocks, zeros are added to the last block of data to make it of the right size.

Comment: That would make sense if I got the data array was a multiple of the block size (512 in this case), and the last bit was padded. But in face the array is the length of the original data (_not_ a multiple of the block size) and has zeros from the last full block up until the end of the array. Does that make sense? So, the array is not too long with zero's padded. It's the correct length (expected length of the data), but missed the last data (all zeros).